# How to prevent asp:menu from dismissing when it is clicked

Tags: asp.net, menu, dismiss

I have a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu that is dismissed when you click on the top level.

See screencast http://www.screencast.com/t/puCmErPVp

I DO NOT want it to be dismissed when it is clicked. I want the menu to stay down.

The menu items are filled by a sitemap.

Is there anything on the Menu object that I can use to get this behavior? Perhaps there is some javascript or CSS I can use to prevent it from disappearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with some Javascript.

Basically, what was happening before was document.body.onclick was set to Menu_HideItems. I changed it so that document.body.onclick would call my own function and check to see what you were clicking on before hiding the menu items.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  function HideMenuOnClick(item) {
  var target;
     if (item.target) {
        target = item.target;
     }
     else if (item.srcElement) {
        target = item.srcElement;
     }

     if (target.className.indexOf("StaticMenuItemStyle") == -1) 
     {
        Menu_HideItems(item);
     }
     else
     {
        return false;
     }
  }

  document.body.onclick = HideMenuOnClick;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have third party component used with asp:menu, if yes you need its source code to modify hover action for `<li>`, if no, there are some client side javascripts or css styles, you can modify them.